# scala execute inside the for loop

Tags: scala

As I know, the following expression

```
     for{i <- 0 to 10
         j <- 0 to 10} {...}
```

equals to

```
  for(i <- 0 to 10) {
     for(j <- 0 to 10) {
        .....
     }
  }
```

but, how to transform the following expression into the first case?

```
  for(i <- 0 to 10) {
     **execute()**
     for(j <- 0 to 10) {
        .....
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply add in a line than runs the execution and stores the result in a variable. Eg.:

```
for{i <- 0 to 10;
    k = doSomethingWith(i);
    j <- 0 to 10} {... do something with any or all of i,j,k ...}
```

If the execution is side-effecting only (ie. return type is Unit), or you don't care about the return value, just assign to underscore. Eg:

```
for{i <- 0 to 10;
    _ = println(s"i = $i");
    j <- 0 to 10} {... do something with i,j ...}
```